# config file in schedule.rb with Rails Whenever gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, cron, whenever

I have a file called config.yml in my /config folder of my rails application.
I also have an initializer: config/initializers/load_config.rb with the following code:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/config.yml")
```

I am using the Whenever gem to set up a cron job, and would like to use my APP_CONFIG to call a function like so:

```
#inside schedule.rb
every 2.hours do
  runner "MyModel.someMethod('#{APP_CONFIG['some_value']}')"
end
```

but the Whenever gem doesn't seem to recognize the config file when I call

```
 whenever --update-crontab mysite
```

How can I incorporate values from my configuration in my schedule.rb file (instead of hard-coding the value)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your `schedule.rb` file to add a `require 'yaml'` statement to the top. Then add the line from your initializer:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/config.yml")
```

Altenatively, you can probably just require the `load_config.rb` file directly. You should be good to go then.

Comment: aha! so the initializers don't get loaded up when load_config.rb does? thanks! i'll give it a go

Comment: worked like a charm! don't need the `require 'yaml'` when I require load_config.rb. thanks, john, you're always so helpful!