# whenever gem schedule.rb file: doesn't recognize RAILS_ROOT variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, whenever

In schedule.rb file, the statement:

```
require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/environment.rb"

 every "10 10 2 * * *" do
      command "mysqldump -u #{@db_username} -p#{@db_password} --single-transaction #{@db_name} > #{@backup_Path}/#{@db_name}.sql 2> log/error_crontab.log"
 end
```

When i try to execute the whenever cmd from terminal, getting the following error:

```
 config/schedule.rb:48:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Whenever::JobList::RAILS_ROOT (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.7.0/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:19:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.7.0/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:19:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.7.0/lib/whenever.rb:16:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.7.0/lib/whenever.rb:16:in `cron'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.7.0/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:40:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.7.0/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:7:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.7.0/bin/whenever:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/whenever:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/whenever:19:in `<main>'
```

i am using the require statement to get the dynamic values from the form to schedule the job. Please help to solve this issue?

Note: i have seen the following stackoverflow queries:
[How to detect Rails environment inside whenever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084500/how-to-detect-rails-environment-inside-whenever)

Following this thread to get dynamic values, but facing problem with require statement.
[Rails - Whenever gem - Dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602418/rails-whenever-gem-dynamic-values)

[Ruby/Rails - Whenever gem - Loop cron tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617915/ruby-rails-whenever-gem-loop-cron-tasks)

[config file in schedule.rb with Rails Whenever gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534622/config-file-in-schedule-rb-with-rails-whenever-gem)

Comment: Rails 3 deprecates `RAILS_ROOT` in favor of `Rails.root`. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Rails.root also throws the same error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Whenever doesn't require or depend on Rails at all, so when it runs, RAILS_ROOT is not defined, however because whenever's schedule.rb is generally kept in /config/schedule.rb, we can make an assumption that it is in a rails project, and set our own RAILS_ROOT like this:

```
# in schedule.rb
RAILS_ROOT = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/..'
```

Edit: in the case that you actually need Rails loaded, do this:

```
# in schedule.rb
# this will require config/environment and load your entire rails environment
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/environment")
```

Comment: A similar approach is described in here: http://groups.google.com/group/whenever-gem/browse_thread/thread/e745f2fb3db7cd49

Comment: i am getting database user id and password from form, hence to pass them to the schedule.rb, i need to load the rails environment in schedule.rb.

Comment: @sudhir In that case, I have updated my answer to actually require and boot Rails.

Answer (score 18):

The whenever developer already answered this question, check this out https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/81

*Javan Whenever no longer attempts to load your Rails environment. However, it does automatically set a path variable to the directory whenever was executed from. This should work just the same:*

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
```

Comment: You are wellcome, I know sometimes its hard to find a solution to a problem, but when I finally find it, I like to share it to help others save time :D...

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 4 try with:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")
```

in your schedule.rb file.
This way you also have access to all your active-record models and initializers.